# EJS Include raw partial without rendering its contents

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm using ejs on `node.js` side to include partials (`glsl` shaders) in to core page inside `script` tags. Afterwards i'm planing to retreive text content of those script tags on client side and dynamically compile them using `EJS` on client side based on client side variables.

Problem is that during initial `<%- include ... %>` on server side `EJS` hooks up own syntaxis inside shaders and attempts to compile them, which I want to avoid.

So it there any way to include those partials just as a simple raw chunk of text disregarding any possible `EJS` syntaxis inside?

core .ejs:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="mandelbrotCalcVertexShader">
    <%- include shaders/mandelbrotCalcVertexShader.glsl %>
</script>
<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="mandelbrotCalcFragmentShader">
    <%- include shaders/mandelbrotCalcFragmentShader.glsl %>
</script>
```

Comment: are you trying to include it as a .ejs file?

Comment: nope, it's `.glsl`

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code. I have the impression the `.glsl` is not in a a script tag.

Comment: @lbu Hm not sure where are you leading, but here it is. That what i've meant by them being in script tags.

Comment: Try including the `<script ...` tag inside the `.glsl` This may cause it to treat it as a literal template.

Comment: Not quite sure what do you mean by that? Wrap contents of .glsl in to script tag? I need contents of that file to be clean from unnecessary garbage, but anyway, tried it - no luck. I'm using ejs 2.2.x btw, and i was pretty sure that compiling everything that is passed to include is an expected behaviour. Will update to latest and check it out

Comment: @lbu, nope, still no luck, though error thrown now is "esc is not a function" but it persist only if there is a EJS syntaxis inside file, so i conclude that its still the same problem

Comment: In that case, the only thing I can think of is to use something like `readFileSync` to get the content of the file in a variable and print it in the right place for each glsl.

Comment: @lbu that is a possible workaround but will require hardcoding of those shader file paths or writing some simple templater able to hook them from file, read and include... or just using another template engine for that... Definetily possible and absolutely inelegant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after all I've made a little hack to ejs source that forces ejs to compile only those files that have .ejs extension. Others are passed as is.
If someone interested in particular edit - in `ejs.js` under `node_modules/ejs/lib` you should find `function handleCache(options, template)` which has `return func;` on bottom.

Swap this return statement with following condition:

```
if (~filename.indexOf(".ejs")) {
    return func;
} else {
    return function() {
      return template;
    };
}
```

Voila!

Maybe I'll make a PR for this thing to be an option. I'm quite surprised that we can't do this natively.